# Pattern of WL.Logger

Tags: logging, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using worklight 6.2 and I'm creating a new application.

For the new application, there is a need to have time-stamps on the logs.
So, is there a way to configure the WL.Logger to print time-stamps without extending it and doing it myself?

I guess WL.Logger is a wrapper to some Loggers like the Java Logger, and I know I can pass a logging pattern to that.

Answer (score 1):

By default logcat already provides a timestamp. But if you wish to provide your own timestamp you will need to extend WL.Logger. You can simply wrap it around a function of your own and pass in your timestamp.